Why is Poool Paywall Not Visible After Navigating Between Pages in Next.js 14.2.5 and React 18?
I'm working on a Next.js (v14.2.5) project with React 18 and the @poool/react-access library (v4.0.0) to integrate a paywall. Here's my setup and the issue I'm facing:
Setup:

Homepage:

Uses Link with prefetch={false} to navigate between pages.



import Link from "next/link";
export default async function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="homepage">
      <Link href='/pool' prefetch={false}>Go to Pool</Link> <br />
    </div>
  );
}


Paywall Page:

The Poool paywall is integrated on this page.



'use client'
import { 
  AccessContext, 
  Paywall, 
  RestrictedContent } from "@poool/react-access";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRef } from "react";


export default function pool() {
  const accessRef = useRef()

  const destroy = () => {
    console.log("ref", accessRef)
    accessRef.current.destroy(accessRef.current.containerRef)
  }

  const recreate = () => {
    console.log("ref", accessRef)
    accessRef.current.recreate()
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <button onClick={destroy}>Destroy</button> <br />
      <button onClick={recreate}>Recreate</button> <br />
      <Link href="/" prefetch={false}>Homepage</Link>
      <br />
      <AccessContext
        appId="<ID>"
        config={{
          debug: true,
          app_name: 'My app',
          cookies_enabled: true,
          content: '[data-poool]',
          mode: 'custom',
          disable_content_height_calculation: true,
          dom_load_timeout: true,
          popover_enabled: true,
          popover_timeout: 500,
        }}>

        <RestrictedContent  >
          <div data-poool />
        </RestrictedContent>
        <Paywall ref={accessRef} />
      </AccessContext>
    </div>
  )
}

Issue:

When I start the server and navigate from the homepage to the paywall page:

The Poool paywall initializes correctly.
Poool debug log first load

The Destroy and Recreate buttons work perfectly.
Poool visibility



However, after navigating back to the homepage Poool debug log and returning to the paywall page:

The Poool paywall is no longer visible.

The Destroy and Recreate buttons stop working.
Poool not visible




Additional info:
Ref details

Recreate on Component Mount:

I attempted to call recreate() when the component mounts to ensure the paywall re-initializes when navigating back to the page. However, this did not fix the issue, as the paywall remains invisible and the buttons (destroy, recreate) do not work.


Destroy on Component Unmount:

I also tried calling destroy() when the component unmounts, thinking that cleaning up the paywall before leaving the page might help reset it upon re-entering. Unfortunately, this approach didn’t resolve the issue either.



